# python-fitbit API update tokens

Tags: python, python-3.x, fitbit

[The docs](http://python-fitbit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#fitbit-api) of the python-fitbit API recommend passing a 'refresh_cb' function as a parameter so we don't have to manually retrieve access tokens, refresh tokens, and expires_at variables each time we want access to the Fitbit API. I have placed these values into environment variables, and each time I retrieve the values manually, I can successfully gain access to my Fitbit information. However, I do not understand what the `refresh_cb` function should do or return. I know that it's meant for me to save the new tokens, but I've only attempted to change the environment variables to the new values, which still kicks out an `(Invalid grant)` error when I try to do anything beyond that. Here's my code so far:

```
from fitbit import Fitbit
import os

CLIENT_ID = os.environ['client_id']
SECRET = os.environ['secret']
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ['access_token']
EXPIRES_AT = os.environ['expires_in']
REFRESH_TOKEN = os.environ['refresh_token']
USER_ID = os.environ['user_id']


def refresh_cb(token_dict):
    """Function for refreshing access_token, refresh_token, and expires_at."""
    os.environ['access_token'] = token_dict['access_token']
    os.environ['expires_at'] = str(token_dict['expires_at'])
    os.environ['refresh_token'] = token_dict['refresh_token']

    return token_dict

kurt = Fitbit(
    CLIENT_ID,
    SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN,
    expires_at=EXPIRES_AT,
    refresh_cb=refresh_cb
)
```

Here's what the docs say:

> We also strongly recommend passing in a refresh_cb keyword argument,
>   which should be a function taking one argument: a token dict. When
>   that argument is present, we will automatically refresh the access
>   token when needed and call this function so that you can save the
>   updated token data. If you don’t save the updated information, then
>   you could end up with invalid access and refresh tokens, and the only
>   way to recover from that is to reauthorize the user. If you have a
>   working example or can point me in the right direction, I'd really
>   appreciate it.

EDIT:

here's the full traceback I'm getting:

```
TokenExpiredError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py in request(self, method, url, data, headers, withhold_token, client_id, client_secret, **kwargs)
    329                 url, headers, data = self._client.add_token(url,
--> 330                         http_method=method, body=data, headers=headers)
    331             # Attempt to retrieve and save new access token if expired

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py in add_token(self, uri, http_method, body, headers, token_placement, **kwargs)
    192         if self._expires_at and self._expires_at < time.time():
--> 193             raise TokenExpiredError()
    194 

TokenExpiredError: (token_expired) 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidGrantError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c92ce9c67530> in <module>()
----> 1 sleep = kurt.sleep()

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fitbit/utils.py in _curried(*moreargs, **morekwargs)
     36 def curry(_curried_func, *args, **kwargs):
     37     def _curried(*moreargs, **morekwargs):
---> 38         return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
     39     return _curried

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fitbit/api.py in _COLLECTION_RESOURCE(self, resource, date, user_id, data)
    313             base_url = "{0}/{1}/user/{2}/{resource}.json"
    314         url = base_url.format(*self._get_common_args(user_id), **kwargs)
--> 315         return self.make_request(url, data)
    316 
    317     def _DELETE_COLLECTION_RESOURCE(self, resource, log_id):

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fitbit/api.py in make_request(self, *args, **kwargs)
    221 
    222         method = kwargs.get('method', 'POST' if 'data' in kwargs else 'GET')
--> 223         response = self.client.make_request(*args, **kwargs)
    224 
    225         if response.status_code == 202:

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fitbit/api.py in make_request(self, url, data, method, **kwargs)
     94             client_id=self.client_id,
     95             client_secret=self.client_secret,
---> 96             **kwargs
     97         )
     98 

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fitbit/api.py in _request(self, method, url, **kwargs)
     66 
     67         try:
---> 68             response = self.session.request(method, url, **kwargs)
     69 
     70             # If our current token has no expires_at, or something manages to slip

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py in request(self, method, url, data, headers, withhold_token, client_id, client_secret, **kwargs)
    341                         auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(client_id, client_secret)
    342                     token = self.refresh_token(
--> 343                         self.auto_refresh_url, auth=auth, **kwargs
    344                     )
    345                     if self.token_updater:

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py in refresh_token(self, token_url, refresh_token, body, auth, timeout, headers, verify, proxies, **kwargs)
    307             r = hook(r)
    308 
--> 309         self.token = self._client.parse_request_body_response(r.text, scope=self.scope)
    310         if not 'refresh_token' in self.token:
    311             log.debug('No new refresh token given. Re-using old.')

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py in parse_request_body_response(self, body, scope, **kwargs)
    406         .. _`Section 7.1`: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-7.1
    407         """
--> 408         self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
    409         self._populate_attributes(self.token)
    410         return self.token

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py in parse_token_response(body, scope)
    377 
    378     params = OAuth2Token(params, old_scope=scope)
--> 379     validate_token_parameters(params)
    380     return params
    381 

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py in validate_token_parameters(params)
    384     """Ensures token precence, token type, expiration and scope in params."""
    385     if 'error' in params:
--> 386         raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
    387 
    388     if not 'access_token' in params:

~/Projects/kurt_data/ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/errors.py in raise_from_error(error, params)
    404     for _, cls in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass):
    405         if cls.error == error:
--> 406             raise cls(**kwargs)

InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant)
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, this issue [has been discussed](https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit/issues/119) on the project's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to refresh global python variables (not environment variables) like this

```
def refresh_cb(token_dict):
    """Function for refreshing access_token, refresh_token, and expires_at."""
    global ACCESS_TOKEN
    global EXPIRES_AT
    global REFRESH_TOKEN
    ACCESS_TOKEN = token_dict['access_token']
    EXPIRES_AT = str(token_dict['expires_at'])
    REFRESH_TOKEN = token_dict['refresh_token']

    return token_dict
```

Comment: I attempted your suggestion, but I am still receiving the same error. I'm basically just instantiating a `Fitbit` class into the variable `kurt` then attempting to get some data. From my understanding, if the `refresh_cb` function is correct, then it will get the new tokens and use the provided function to save them.